# Number Format exceptions when reading a text file

Tags: java

I am reading in a text file that contains a dataset in several columns. I'm using a Memreader and I have assigned each column as an index so that I print the outputs to a destination file. I however for the life of me can't figure out why I keep getting this 'Number format exception'. I have done the usual obj.nextLine() to skip the header and i have assigned 'int' data types to all the values in the dataset and made sure the dataset was only of int values for easier testing but still getting the error.. Here is my code:

```
   public class MemReader implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7526472295622776147L;

public OpenIntObjectHashMap movieToCust;
public OpenIntObjectHashMap custToMovie;
public OpenIntIntHashMap sumByCust;
public OpenIntIntHashMap sumByMovie;


/**
 * Default constructor. Initializes hashtables. 
 */
public MemReader() {
    movieToCust = new OpenIntObjectHashMap();
    custToMovie = new OpenIntObjectHashMap();    
    sumByCust = new OpenIntIntHashMap();
    sumByMovie = new OpenIntIntHashMap();
}


/**
 * Reads a text file in the form 
 *
 * mid,uid,rating
 *
 * and stores this data in the custToMovie and 
 * movieToCust hashtables. 
 *
 * @param  fileName  The file containing the movie
 *                   data in the specified format.
 */
public void readData(String fileName) {

    try {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

        String[] line;
        int mid;   //user-id
        int uid; //isbn
        int rating;  //book rating
        //String date;


        while(in.hasNextLine()) {

            line = in.nextLine().split(", ");
            mid = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
            uid = Integer.parseInt(line[1]);  //isbn change
            rating = Integer.parseInt(line[2]);

            addToMovies(mid, uid, rating);
            addToCust(mid, uid, rating);

        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Can't find file " + fileName);
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


/**
 * Serializes a MemReader object so that it can be
 * read back later. 
 *
 * @param  fileName  The file to serialize to. 
 * @param  obj  The name of the MemReader object to serialize.
 */
public static void serialize(String fileName, MemReader obj) {

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        os.writeObject(obj);
        os.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Can't find file " + fileName);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


/**
 * Deserializes a previously serialized MemReader object. 
 *
 * @param  fileName  The file containing the serialized object. 
 * @return The deserialized MemReader object. 
 */
public static MemReader deserialize(String fileName)
{
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        return (MemReader) in.readObject();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Can't find class");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //We should never get here
    return null;
}




/**
 * Adds an entry to the movieToCust hashtable. The
 * uid and rating are packed into one int to 
 * conserve memory. 
 *
 * @param  mid  The movie id. 
 * @param  uid  The user id. 
 * @param  rating  User uid's rating for movie mid.
 */
//NOTE THIS EDITED PART
public void addToMovies(int mid, int uid, int rating) {

    IntArrayList list;

    if(mid == 0 && uid == 0)
        return;

    if(movieToCust.containsKey(mid)) {
        list = (IntArrayList) movieToCust.get(mid);
    }
    else {
        list = new IntArrayList();
    }

    list.add(uid<<8 | rating);
    movieToCust.put(mid, list);

    int sum = sumByMovie.get(mid);
    sumByMovie.put(mid, sum + rating);

}


/**
 * Adds an entry to the custToMovie hashtable. The
 * mid and rating are packed into one int to 
 * conserve memory. 
 *
 * @param  mid  The movie id. 
 * @param  uid  The user id. 
 * @param  rating  User uid's rating for movie mid.
 */
public void addToCust(int mid, int uid, int rating) {

    IntArrayList list;

    if(mid == 0 && uid == 0)
        return;

    if(custToMovie.containsKey(uid))
        list = (IntArrayList) custToMovie.get(uid);
    else
        list = new IntArrayList();

    list.add(mid<<8 | rating);
    custToMovie.put(uid, list);

    int sum = sumByCust.get(uid);
    sumByCust.put(uid, sum + rating);
}


/**
 * Sorts each entry in the movieToCust and 
 * custToMovie hashes to allow for efficient
 * searching. 
 */
public void sortHashes() {
    Sorter sorter = new Sorter();
    movieToCust.forEachPair(sorter);
    custToMovie.forEachPair(sorter);
}


/**
 * This class is used with the forEachPair method
 * of an OpenIntObjectHashMap when the Object is 
 * an IntArrayList. The apply method sorts the 
 * IntArrayList in ascending order. 
 */
private class Sorter implements IntObjectProcedure{

    /**
     * Sorts the IntArrayList in ascending order. 
     *
     * @param  first  uid or mid
     * @param  second IntArrayList of ratings. 
     * @return true
     */
    public boolean apply(int first, Object second) {
        IntArrayList list = (IntArrayList) second;
        list.trimToSize();
        list.sortFromTo(0, list.size() -1);
        return true;
    }
}


public static void main(String args[]){

    MemReader reader = new MemReader();

    String sourceFile = null;
    String destFile = null;

    try {
        sourceFile = args[0];
        destFile = args[1];

        reader.readData(sourceFile);
        reader.sortHashes();


        IntArrayList users = reader.custToMovie.keys();

        for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(users.get(i));
        }


        serialize(destFile, reader);


    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("usage: java MemReader sourceFile destFile");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}
Here is the sample data I will be using:

```
 user movie rating
 1       1      5
 1       2      3
 1       10     3
 1       32     4
 1       34     4
 1       47     3
 1       50     4
 1       62     4
 1       150    4
 1       153    3
 1       160    3
 1       161    4
 1       165    4
 1       185    3
 1       208    3
 1       253    3
 1       265    5
 1       266    3
 1       288    5
 1       292    4
 1       296    5
 1       300    5
```

and here is the error I am getting. Any help will be appreciated. I'm sure it's something small that I am missing and just need a fresh pair of eyes. regards.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "user,movie,rating"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at memreader.MemReader.readData(MemReader.java:73)
at memreader.MemReader.main(MemReader.java:259)
```

Comment: Insert a `in.nextLine()` before your while loop, to skip over the header line.

Comment: "I however for the life of me can't figure out why I keep getting this 'Number format exception'." Did you read the message for the exception, that shows you what input failed?

Answer (score 5):

You are reading first line which does not contains any number. Also your file is not seperated by comma. Why do you split by comma? Split by space

Answer (score 0):

Add `if(in.hasNext()) in.nextLine();` before your `while` loop to skip first line.

Comment: Alternatively, add a line counter and do no parsing when it's zero. This way, you don't risk calling `in.nextLine()` on an empty file.

Answer (score 0):

for first line is "user,movie,rating" after splitting you will get all string not int, so you need to skip the first line. add in.nextLine() before while loop to skip the first line

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have included the required output instead of Inout separated by commas. Please note that `Integer.parseInt()`, `Float.parseFloat()`, `Double.parseDouble()` etc will throw `NumberFormatException` (runtime) when it can't parse the input. It expects the input to be `Integer` in your case.

Either catch it appropriately or skip the first line that has headers using `in.nextLine()` before start of while loop. Doing this, will move the scanner to second line before you start parsing the digits.